# Finding a lower bound for $\frac{\Gamma\left(2x+2 - \frac{1.25506(x+1)}{\ln(x+1)}\right)}{\Gamma\left(2x - \frac{1.25506(x)}{\ln x}\right)}$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, solution-verification, gamma-function

Does it follow that for $x > e^3$, $\dfrac{\Gamma\left(2x+2 - \frac{1.25506(x+1)}{\ln(x+1)}\right)}{\Gamma\left(2x - \frac{1.25506(x)}{\ln x}\right)} > \dfrac{\Gamma\left(x+8 - \frac{1.25506}{\ln x}\right)}{\Gamma(x+6)}$

Note:  My interest in $\dfrac{1.25506x}{\ln x}$ comes from this [upper bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities) for the prime counting function:

$$\pi(x) < \dfrac{1.25506x}{\ln x}$$

Here is my thinking:

(1)  $f(x) = \dfrac{1.25506x}{\ln x}$ is an increasing function at $x > e$ since:

- $f'(x) = \dfrac{1.25506\ln(x) - 1.25506}{(\ln x)^2}$ is positive when $\ln(x) > 1$
- It follows that: $\dfrac{1.25506(x+1)}{\ln (x+1)} - \dfrac{1.25506x}{\ln x}> 0$

(2) $\dfrac{1.25506(x+1)}{\ln (x+1)} - \dfrac{1.25506x}{\ln x} < \dfrac{1.25506}{\ln x}$ since:

$$\dfrac{1.25506(x+1)}{\ln (x+1)} - \dfrac{1.25506x}{\ln x} < \dfrac{1.25506(x+1)}{\ln(x)} - \dfrac{1.25506x}{\ln x} = \dfrac{1.25506}{\ln x}$$

(3)  From the [log convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_convex_function) property of the Gamma function, does it follows that for all positive real $a,b,c$

$$\dfrac{\Gamma(a+b))}{\Gamma(a)} < \dfrac{\Gamma(a+b+c)}{\Gamma(a+c)}$$

(4)  if $x > e^3$, then $2x - \dfrac{1.25506(x+1)}{\ln(x+1)} > x+6$

- $\ln(x+1) > 1.25506 + 1$
- $x\ln(x+1) > 1.25506x + x > 1.25506(x+1) + (x-1.25506)$
- $x > \dfrac{1.25506(x+1)}{\ln(x+1)} +  \dfrac{x-1.25506}{\ln(x+1)}> \dfrac{1.25506(x+1)}{\ln(x+1)} + 6$
- $2x - \dfrac{1.25506(x+1)}{\ln(x+1)} > x+6$

(5)  From step(2) and (3), for $x \ge e^2$, it follows that if $s = 2-\left(2x+2 - \frac{1.25506(x+1)}{\ln(x+1)}\right) + \left(2x - \frac{1.25506(x)}{\ln x}\right)$, then:

- $1 < s < 2$
- $\dfrac{\Gamma\left(2x+2 - \frac{1.25506(x+1)}{\ln(x+1)}\right)}{\Gamma\left(2x - \frac{1.25506(x)}{\ln x}\right)} =  \dfrac{\Gamma\left(2x - \frac{1.25506(x)}{\ln(x)}+s\right)}{\Gamma\left(2x - \frac{1.25506(x)}{\ln x}\right)} > \dfrac{\Gamma\left(2x - \frac{1.25506(x+1)}{\ln(x+1)}+s\right)}{\Gamma\left(2x - \frac{1.25506(x+1)}{\ln (x+1)}\right)} > \dfrac{\Gamma\left(2x - \frac{1.25506(x+1)}{\ln(x+1)}+2 - \frac{1.25506}{\ln x}\right)}{\Gamma\left(2x - \frac{1.25506(x+1)}{\ln (x+1)}\right)}$

(6)  From step(4) and step(3):

$\dfrac{\Gamma\left(2x - \frac{1.25506(x+1)}{\ln(x+1)}+2 - \frac{1.25506}{\ln x}\right)}{\Gamma\left(2x - \frac{1.25506(x+1)}{\ln (x+1)}\right)} > \dfrac{\Gamma\left(x+8 - \frac{1.25506}{\ln x}\right)}{\Gamma(x+6)}$

Comment: Without kidding you (be sure), you seem fascinated by the series of problems with $\frac{1.25506}{\log(x)}$. Cheers :-)

Comment: I am working on an alternative proof for Sylvester-Schur based on this equation.  I find the Gamma function non-intuitive which is the reason for all the questions on the same topic.

Comment: I added an answer to one of your questions (may 19)

Comment: I answered another question and I think that I understood why we need more accurate calculations. In my humble opinion, playing with so many inequalities may hide things. If you need other calculations of this type, feel free to ping me. Cheers :-)

Comment: Thanks, Claude!  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be true even for $x=e$.

Let $x=e+\epsilon$ and developing as Taylor series around $\epsilon=0$, the numerical evalution of the terms gives $$\log \left(\frac{\text{lsh}}{\text{rhs}}\right)=0.0337736+0.189071 \epsilon +O\left(\epsilon ^2\right)$$ which is zero if $\epsilon=-0.178629$ that is to say $x=2.53965$.

Using again Newton method, the iterates are 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 2.53965 \\
 1 & 2.57365 \\
 2 & 2.57590 \\
 3 & 2.57591
\end{array}
\right)$$